# How to prevent PPA to upgrade all packages instead of desired one

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

I added the [Yorba ppa](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to get the latest version of Geary. Now  when I went to upgrade my system next, it tried to also pull a later version of Shotwell from their PPA as well, but the upgrade failed because it conflicted with the way Ubuntu installs shotwell.

Now, I could purge the shotwell* packages and then install again and it will pull from the Yorba PPA fine, but how can I tell apt to only use shotwell from the Ubuntu repositories, even if the Yorba PPA has a later version?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more than one version of same package is available, in this case you can install specific version of package using `sudo apt-get install packagename=version`

To find the available version of shotwell use

```
 apt-cache policy shotwell
```

On my Ubuntu 12.04 it was

```
Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.14.1-1~precise1
  Version table:
     0.14.1-1~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     0.12.3-0ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
     0.12.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

So I tried

```
 sudo apt-get install shotwell=0.12.3-0ubuntu0.1
```

But it gave me error for  `libgexiv2-1` package. 
So I applied `apt-cache policy  libgexiv2-1` to find conflict and found it is also available in the PPA.

So to install `shotwell` from Ubuntu repo I used following  command

```
  sudo apt-get install shotwell=0.12.3-0ubuntu0.1 libgexiv2-1=0.4.1-1build1
```

It installed  shotwell successfully from the Official Ubuntu repo.

```
shotwell --version
Shotwell 0.12.3
```

---

**EDIT**

***Pinning  a Package***

As you specified you want to receive  upgrade only for Geary, not for other packages from this PPA. For this you can use [Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

- Create a pinning config file using

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu-geary-pin-400
  ```

  with following contents.

  ```
  Package: *
  Pin: release o=LP-PPA-yorba
  Pin-Priority: 400

  Package: *geary*
  Pin: release o=LP-PPA-yorba
  Pin-Priority: 500
  ```

  *(Here it is first assigning priority of 400 to every packages in yorba ppa and     then after it is assigning 500 priority(which is normal priority) to geary package.)*
- Save it.

Now you will receive upgrade from this ppa only for geary

Comment: Yep, that works for installing.  However, when you next did a `update && upgrade`, it would've tried to upgrade to the newer version from the repository you didn't want.  Installing is fine, I want Ubuntu to only update from a particular repository for a particular package.

Comment: apt  will update index for all the entries present in /etc/apt/sources.list. If you do not want to update some ppa, make a backup of your source.list and remove the ppa entry followed by `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Right, but the PPA has many packages.  I want to use the PPA for Geary, but not for Shotwell.

Comment: There we go.  That will point me in the right direction I guess, thanks.

Comment: if you showed the actual config, it would have solved my problem.

Comment: edited.  14.04.1.