# Is Gedit-3.14.2 available for ubuntu?

Tags: ppa, gedit, programming

From where I will get gedit latest version? Current I have 3.10.4 installed on my Ubuntu version 14.10. Do we have any ppa available to download latest gedit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Comment: If I am not wrong, I am asking about gedit not GNOME.

Comment: Gedit is part of the GNOME set.

Comment: OK, so along with latest GNOME it will add lastet Gedit also.

Comment: But wanted to add that individually instead of along with GNOME.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/531562/how-to-prevent-ppa-to-upgrade-all-packages-instead-of-desired-one, and combined with the [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/testing) (and the  ones listed in it) should get you the latest Gedit.

Comment: Although you will be able to install Gedit 3.14.2 using the PPA provided, do remember that it is a *staging* (or bleeding edge) repo and may cause stability issues, especially since other GNOME packages will also be simultaneously updated.

Comment: Ubuntu's GNOME team maintain a PPA that contains newer versions of GNOME libraries and applications, among them gedit -- see http://askubuntu.com/questions/616700/how-to-get-new-face-of-gedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1.`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:suraia/ppa`  then

2.`sudo apt-get update` then

3.`sudo apt-get remove gedit && sudo apt-get install gedit` then

4.`sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:suraia/ppa`then **REBOOT** and

5.`gedit -V` you should see the version of gedit.

idk if it really helps but try

Comment: Why reboot? You're just reinstalling an application. Also, please note that this will install gedit from a completely untrusted, random PPA off the Internet.

Comment: Tried to add the ppa but got error saying that: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~suraia/ubuntu/ppa'.`
`The user named '~suraia' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ppa'`
`Please choose from the following available PPAs:`
 `* 'server':  Server`

Comment: For suraia ppa, you have to write `ppa:suraia/server` and not `ppa:suraia/ppa`. **Yet**, it seems that he has removed gedit packages from his ppa.

Comment: gedit 3.14.3 is now available in [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) for vivid vervet. I already had GNOME3 installed from the main Ubuntu repositories. When I added the PPA, I found it didn't make that many changes to my system (just 18 new packages).

Comment: Well I tried all the repositories listed here in answer and comments, but I always get gedit 3.10.4 version only even after upgrade, my Ubuntu version is 14.04 Trusty Tahr, I really need a 3-4 step procedure to upgrade my Gedit to 3.14.3 or later without breaking gedit plugins like external tools which are listed in tools menu, just simple as adding repo, apt update and then install, but I can't find one procedure like that. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the version you want is not in the official PPAs (for 14.04 LTS it looks like it's currently [gedit (3.10.4-0ubuntu4)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome/gedit)) there can be good reasons for this, mainly that newer versions are not tested, not considered stable, et cetera.

If you really want to try newer versions of software, you can usually get newer versions directly from the respective web pages of the applications themselves. Googling for gedits website showed that they do have a library of source packages:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/

The bleeding edge seems to be 3.14.2 (as you request) and it was put up on Dec 4th. No wonder it's not in the PPAs! Download [gedit-3.14.2.tar.xz](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit/3.14/gedit-3.14.2.tar.xz) and [install the application from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get remove gedit libgtksourceview-3.0-common
sudo apt-get install gedit=3.4.1-0ubuntu1 gedit-common=3.4.1-0ubuntu1 \
     libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common=3.4.1-0ubuntu1 \
     gir1.2-gtksource-3.0=3.4.1-0ubuntu1
```

That installed the latest version of gedit as of this comment.