# How to get new face of gedit

Tags: gedit, ubuntu-gnome

Iam not being able to get the new face of Gedit. The new look came with gnome 3.14 and I am currently running ubuntu gnome 15.04 with gnome version 3.14

Comment: what version of `gedit` are you using? Is it `3.10`?

Comment: Yes I checked it now its still 3.10 and I am not being able to update as it is showing no update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can install `gedit 3.14.3` in `ubuntu 15.04`. Run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove gedit && sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Type `gedit --version` to see the version.

This is how it looks in my computer:

[image]

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` is enough. A removal is not necessary.

Comment: Doesn't work  my system Ubuntu 14.04 version. After update still installs old version 3.10.4 and not 3.14.3

Comment: @VickyDev This is for 15.04. You can try [somthing else](http://askubuntu.com/questions/566893/is-gedit-3-14-2-available-for-ubuntu)